# Maven generate achetype in existed directory

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create empty Maven Web Project with an existing dir (actually from *github* project, it's empty and contains only *README* file).

But maven seems to detect directory existence and failed with error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Directory loms already exists - please run from a clean directory -> [Help 1]
```

Any chance to force maven use an existing directory?

***Invocation command:***

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.reaver.devs -DartifactId=loms -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: Why not simply delete that directory prior to creating the project?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Because that directory already contains the `.git` directory, I guess ...

Answer (score 1):

The [quickstart archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#creating-a-project) works fine for this. It gives a warning but then creates the pom.xml and the maven `src/` directory structure inside an existing directory (i.e. the same as the artifactId).

It must be run from the **PARENT** directory.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the directory is already existing, maven won't be able to generate another artifact project with same name. And since your *loms* directory is a git project and it is not acceptable to delete it, you can follow a tricky way:

- Generate a project with your desired archetype but with diferrent artifact name (just will serve as a swap directory):

  ```
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.reaver.devs \
                         -DartifactId=loms-2 \
                         -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
                         -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
                         -DinteractiveMode=false
  ```
- The above command will generate a new directory with maven nature, and it absolutely fits in what you are expecting for your *loms* project, expect the `<artifactId>` in your *pom.xml* which must be updated to *loms* (note that I will be using command lines but you may use any visual tools to update the file):

  ```
  vi pom.xml
  ```
- Remove the *-2* suffixe in the `artifactId` so it matched *loms*.
- Copy all files/folders under *loms-2/* directory to your project directory *loms/*.
- Now you have your project initialized.

Comment: Well, I know about tricky ways. Actually if rename already existed dir into temp-name and create loms project you are really have no need for correct pom.xml after merging. But question is how to do it without tricks, crunches, hacks. Some option for maven.

Comment: There is no options for Maven then.

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried to do the same. I found that the following works for my use case, where a) the remote repository is always created with a `main` branch containing only a basic `README.md`, and b) we use PRs for everything, even the first actual commit.

After using the archetype to create the folder, I executed the following commands in the newly created folder:

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch origin
git branch -m feature/setup
git add .
git commit -m "Initial setup"
git rebase -Xtheirs origin/main
```

- The first two commands are straightforward, and are used when pushing to an empty remote repository.
- The fetch retrieves a reference to `origin/main`.
- The renaming is perhaps unnecessary for you, if `master` is a valid name. I don't know how this works if the remote branch is also called `master`.
- The add and commit are also straightforward.
- The rebase resolves conflicts in favour of the newly created branch, in other words what the archetype created.

After this I can add more commits, or push and let the PR be completed as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `archetypeGroupId` property, your invocation will succeed without the error.

```
mkdir loms
echo hi >loms/README.md
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
  -DgroupId=org.reaver.devs -DartifactId=loms \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
tree loms
```

Result:

```
loms
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml
```